# Ubuntu 18.04 NO AUDIO problem for some work

Tags: drivers, windows, 18.04

I upgraded to ubuntu 18.04 everything works fine except audio . there is no Audio output from speakers/headphone. I tried almost everything i can think of.. but here is the thing.. \
I used command `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio" 
and here is the output

```
--00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 131
    Memory at ef328000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at ef300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
```

I figured out snd_hda_intel is my driver but tried to use it via modprobe its not working//\
here is the thing i have dual boot system I thought maybe Windows drivers conflicting? Sounds crazy but i uninstalled windows drives came back to Ubuntu ... ANd Voila! Ubuntu sounds were back .. but when i reinstalled windows audio driver again no sound from UbunTU\\
Help me here////

Answer (score 0):

I was through a similar problem only difference is my USB headphone was working.

Somehow this worked
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2197749

Closing the screen lid and opening again, voila sound was back.