# Problem with sound ,headphones

Tags: sound, 18.04, pulseaudio, headphones, pavucontrol

I recently installed 18.04,I know little about it.I hope to improve my current knowledge.

I noticed after yesterday's update,headphones are not getting detected,But I'm able to hear from the speaker.
I'm using the headphones  through pavucontrol but the sound is not clear there is some kind of noise.Without it no detection.

`00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 3ec2 (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e92
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device a379 (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device a36d (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device a36f (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device a360 (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a352 (rev 10)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a33f (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a303 (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a348 (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device a323 (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a324 (rev 10)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 16)`

And This.

```
lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 3ec2 (rev 07)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 5000
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Capabilities: <access denied>

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e92 (prog-if 
00 [VGA controller])                  
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device d000
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126
Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
[virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915

00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device a379 (rev   
10)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 8888
Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
Memory at a121c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal

0:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device a36d (rev 10) (prog-if 30 
[XHCI])     
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 5007
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
Memory at a1200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device a36f (rev 10)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
Flags: fast devsel
Memory at a1216000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=8K]
Memory at a121b000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device a360 (rev 10)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 1c3a
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127
Memory at a121a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: mei_me
Kernel modules: mei_me

00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a352 (rev 10) (prog-if  
01 [AHCI 1.0])
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device b005
Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
Memory at a1214000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
Memory at a1219000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
I/O ports at 4070 [size=8]
I/O ports at 4060 [size=4]
I/O ports at 4040 [size=32]
Memory at a1218000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ahci
Kernel modules: ahci

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a33f (rev f0) (prog-if 00   
[Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
Memory behind bridge: a1100000-a11fffff
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a303 (rev 10)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 5001
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a348 (rev 10)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device a182
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 128
Memory at a1210000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Memory at a1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device a323 (rev 10)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 5001
Flags: medium devsel
Memory at 8f800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=256]
I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
Kernel modules: i2c_i801

00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a324 (rev 
10)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
Flags: fast devsel
Memory at fe010000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]

01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co.,Ltd.
RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 16)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Onboard Ethernet
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
Memory at a1104000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at a1100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
```

I tried the solutions of the FOSS website.It did not work.
Can you help me resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

That's helped me to solve the problem with my sound after upgrading ubuntu:

[Ubuntu 18.04 NO AUDIO problem for some work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051923/ubuntu-18-04-no-audio-problem-for-some-work/1061506#1061506?newreg=22110e2882d54ca887f5d81e64c51b66)

To summarize: I had a hiss instead of sound. And after following the adviсe "with the everything running, close your laptop screen and open it back up" my sound came back.

Comment: Hello and welcome to AU.  It is good practice here to summarize the link you refer to (in case it disappears).  This is in your case even more more important since it refers to further links.  So could you summarize what steps exactly you followed to solve the problem?

Comment: @pronata I tried.It didn't work.I also did force reload but not worked.